# GKE cluster on GCP doesn't scale nodes properly

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

when pods scale it's almost instantinous (you delete pod, new one spawns) or when you setup HPA (HorizontalPodAutoscaling) with 50% cpu or other custom metric it just spawns new pods. The problem I have right now is even with enabled Node autoscaling on cluster they refuse to do so. Even when I set that I wanted 3nodes per zone (9total) it stays at 6, and with 1-5 or 3-5 autoscaling enabled pods are still throwing this error, any thoughts ?

```
Warning  FailedScheduling   57s (x28 over 39m)     default-scheduler   0/6 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory, 5 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

[image]

Comment: not sure about GCP, but on AKS (microsoft), resources have been prioritized for gov and med, we had a lot of problems scaling during corona. maybe there's some similar announcement for google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason could be that you're using a fixed [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) for all pods. Take a look at the error message:

```
... 5 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

Out of 6 nodes, your pods are trying to be scheduled on a single node skipping the other 5 nodes. As you've enabled auto-scaling of nodes, maybe 6 nodes are enough to house all of your running resources that's why there are only 6 nodes.

I will suggest you use [Affinity and Anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) to distribute your pods over multiple zones instead of using fixed `nodeSlector`.

Comment: well you are semi right because the resource that couldn't scale there is the 'default scheduler' :D so it must be on that node, same as other 'default' pods from kube-system